# WPF PasswordChanged property not detecting backspace delete

Tags: c#, wpf, passwordbox

I'm using passwordchanged property in passwordbox:

```
 PasswordChanged="NewPWBox_PasswordChanged"
```

For detecting "real-time" change in password and update my other control which shows how much complex password is.
It works just fine.

Only problem is when i mark whole text and delete it with backspace it dont detect change in string and my others control wont update.

I'm really not an frontend guy and couldn't find solution anywhere for this problem.

My function to show complexity of pasword:

```
private void NewPWBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string NewPass = NewPWBox.Password;

        PasswordScore passwordStrengthScore = PasswordAdvisor.CheckStrength(NewPass);

        switch (passwordStrengthScore)
        {
            case PasswordScore.VeryWeak:

                if(passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.VeryWeak)
                {
                    VW_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    VW_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }

                //hide others
                Weak_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Weak_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Medium_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Medium_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Strong_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Strong_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                VS_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                VS_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                break;
            case PasswordScore.Weak:

                if(passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.Weak)
                {
                    VW_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    VW_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Weak_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Weak_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }

                //hide others
                Medium_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Medium_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Strong_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Strong_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                VS_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                VS_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                break;
            case PasswordScore.Medium:

                if(passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.Medium)
                {
                    VW_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    VW_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Weak_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Weak_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Medium_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Medium_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }

                //hide others
                Strong_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Strong_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                VS_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                VS_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                break;
            case PasswordScore.Strong:

                if(passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.Strong)
                {
                    VW_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    VW_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Weak_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Weak_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Medium_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Medium_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Strong_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Strong_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }

                //hide others
                VS_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                VS_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                break;
            case PasswordScore.VeryStrong:

                if(passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.VeryStrong)
                {
                    VW_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    VW_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Weak_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Weak_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Medium_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Medium_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Strong_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    Strong_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    VS_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    VS_Label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here how it counts complexity:

```
    public enum PasswordScore
    {
        Blank = 0,
        VeryWeak = 1,
        Weak = 2,
        Medium = 3,
        Strong = 4,
        VeryStrong = 5
    }

    public class PasswordAdvisor
    {

        public static PasswordScore CheckStrength(string password)
        {
            int score = 1;
            if (password.Length < 1)
                return PasswordScore.Blank;
            if (password.Length < 4)
                return PasswordScore.VeryWeak;

            if (password.Length >= 8)
                score++;
            if (password.Length >= 12)
                score++;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?", RegexOptions.ECMAScript))   //number only //"^\d+$" if you need to match more than one digit.
                score++;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(password, @"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).+$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)) //both, lower and upper case
                score++;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)) //^[A-Z]+$
                score++;
            return (PasswordScore)score;
        }
```

I dont think you need it but just to be sure if i didnt miss anything.

Any ideas guys?

Thanks and best regards,

John

Comment: Try to handle with KeyUp event.

Comment: @Eldar There is no way to make property detect changes even when deleted with backspace?

Comment: That depends how the PasswordChanged event implemented. Probably they are not firing it when you hit backspace or delete buttons

Comment: "when i mark whole text and delete it with backspace it dont detect change" - can't reproduce. event works (my project is targeting .NET 4.5.2 and running on Window 7). [mcve] needed

Comment: @ASh im on .net 4.8 and WIN10

Comment: @ASh i added code which im using

Comment: How is your XAML?
If you do it by binding with firing onpropertychanged occur the same? Have you tried to catch KeyUp or Down, or TextInput? In KeyUp or TextInput you might be able to catch and do the event correctly

Comment: @DrkDeveloper I only have PasswordChanged="NewPWBox_PasswordChanged" in my PasswordBox. I didnt try it with OnPropertyChange because this was just so much easier.

Comment: As I said, TextInput event must fire even if PasswordChanged not, try it.

Comment: @DrkDeveloper Not firing at all for some reason. But passwordchange works. It fires everytime string changes. Only when i delete it with backspace thats the only time it wont fire.

Comment: KeyUp and KeyDown not firing? Wow, that's a bug.

Comment: @DrkDeveloper keydown is firing, but do the same stuff and its even worse because it wont update when im deleting one by one which passwordchange detect

Comment: This is one fast testing i did right now: (don't care about solution explorer) https://i.imgur.com/P5y6K5G.png  Something it must be slightly wrong i think

Comment: The only solution i'm thinking right now is you test your code in 4.7.2 or lower, if it works, it's a 4.8 problem (that will be weird) if not... Honestly, i don't know, :(.

Comment: @DrkDeveloper deleting one by one with backspace works for me too but did you try to delete more characters with backspace if it will fire? So i did similar test and it seems it will fire but it wont update my controls...

Comment: Yep, it works perfectly fine: https://i.imgur.com/p3S632Q.png

Comment: @JohnyCorbie That's a different problem, if don't update your other controls maybe is because bad bindings or not doing properly things and sets in codebehind

Comment: Why even im dealing with that. I just can add if statement when textbox is empty and then hide all my controls :D Im so stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all chatty comments: 
Put a default case in your switch and hide controls in that case.

Edit: It will be nice if you cut the number of controls to one rectangle and one label and change the color (and the size if you want, or gradientbrush...) and the text of the label... And hide if empty password box.

It's so easy, clean, future proof and more decoupled with binding and validations...